# How to merge array of hashes with nested array

Tags: ruby

I have a dataset similar to the following:

```
[
  {:option_id => 10, :option_style_ids => [9, 10, 11]},
  {:option_id => 7, :option_style_ids => [19]},
  {:option_id => 8, :option_style_ids => [1]},
  {:option_id => 5, :option_style_ids => [4, 5]},
  {:option_id => 10, :option_style_ids => [9, 10, 11]},
  {:option_id => 7, :option_style_ids => [19]},
  {:option_id => 5, :option_style_ids => [4, 5]},
  {:option_id => 8, :option_style_ids => [1]},
  {:option_id => 12, :option_style_ids => [20]},
  {:option_id => 5, :option_style_ids => [2, 5]}
]
```

I would like to merge the dataset for an output of:

```
[
  {:option_id => 10, :option_style_ids => [9, 10, 11]},
  {:option_id => 7, :option_style_ids => [19]},
  {:option_id => 8, :option_style_ids => [1]},
  {:option_id => 5, :option_style_ids => [2, 4, 5]},
  {:option_id => 12, :option_style_ids => [20]}
]
```

The above output strips the duplicates, however, for the `option_id: 5` hashes, I need it to combines the `option_style_ids` array values (some of which are different).

I tried:

```
r.group_by{|h| h[:option_id]}.map{|k,v| v.reduce(:merge)}
```

Unfortunately, that did not combine the `option_style_ids` array values.

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer if you find any to be helpful.

Comment: I chose @sawa 's answer because it was the most concise

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, you can upvote answers. I mention this because I noticed you didn't upvote the answer you selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array.group_by{|h| h[:option_id]}.values.map do
  |a| a.inject{|h, _h| h.merge(_h){|k, v, _v| k == :option_id ? v : (v + _v).uniq}}
end
# => [
#   {:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]},
#   {:option_id=>7, :option_style_ids=>[19]},
#   {:option_id=>8, :option_style_ids=>[1]},
#   {:option_id=>5, :option_style_ids=>[4, 5, 2]},
#   {:option_id=>12, :option_style_ids=>[20]}
# ]
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `Hash#merge!`), using the form that employs a block to determine that values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

**Code**

```
def merge_em(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
    h.update(g[:option_id]=>g) do |_,o,n|
      { :option_id=>o[:option_id],
        :option_style_ids=>o[:option_style_ids] | n[:option_style_ids] }
    end
  end.values
end
```

**Example**

For the array given in the question, which I'll refer to as `arr`:

```
merge_em(arr) 
  #=> [{:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]},
  #    {:option_id=> 7, :option_style_ids=>[19]},
  #    {:option_id=> 8, :option_style_ids=>[1]},
  #    {:option_id=> 5, :option_style_ids=>[4, 5, 2]},
  #    {:option_id=>12, :option_style_ids=>[20]}]
```

**Explanation**

To explain what's going on, let me simplify `arr`:

```
arr = [
  { :option_id => 10, :option_style_ids => [9, 10, 11] },
  { :option_id =>  7, :option_style_ids => [19] },
  { :option_id => 10, :option_style_ids => [9, 12] }
]
```

The steps:

```
enum = arr.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [
  #     {:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]},
  #     {:option_id=> 7, :option_style_ids=>[19]},
  #     {:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 12]}
  #   ]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can view the elements of `enum` by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[{:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]}, {}],
  #    [{:option_id=> 7, :option_style_ids=>[19]}, {}],
  #    [{:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 12]}, {}]]
```

As you see, `enum` contains three elements.

The first element of `enum` is passed to the block and assigned to the block variables:

```
g,h = enum.next
  #=> [{:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]}, {}] 
g #=> {:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]} 
h #=> {}
```

We now perform the block calculation:

```
h.update(g[:option_id]=>g)
  #=> {}.update(10=>{:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]}
  #   {10=>{:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]}}
```

`update` returns the new value of `h`.

In merging `{ 10=>g }` into `h` (Ruby permits the shorthand `(10=>g)` for this), `h` does not have a key `10`, so `update`'s block is not consulted in determining the merged value for `h[10]`.

The next element of `enum` is passed to the block:

```
g,h = enum.next
  #=> [{:option_id=>7, :option_style_ids=>[19]},
  #=>  {10=>{:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]}}] 
g #=>  {:option_id=>7, :option_style_ids=>[19]} 
h #=>  {10=>{:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]}}
```

Notice that `h` has been updated.

We now perform the block calculation:

```
h.update(g[:option_id]=>g)
  #=> {10=>{:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]}}
  #     .update(7=>{:option_id=>7, :option_style_ids=>[19]}) 
  #=>   {10=>{:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]},
  #       7=>{:option_id=> 7, :option_style_ids=>[19]}}
```

Again, `h` does not have a key `7`, so `update`'s block is not used.

The last element of `enum` is now passed to the block and the block calculation is performed:

```
g,h = enum.next
g #=> {:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 12]} 
h #=> {10=>{:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]},
  #     7=>{:option_id=> 7, :option_style_ids=>[19]}} 

h.update(10=>g)
```

This time `h` contains the key (`10`) of the hash being merged into `h` (`{ 10=>g }`). `update`'s block is therefore called up upon to determine the value for that key in the merged hash. The block is passed an array of three elements:

```
k,o,n = [10, h[10], g]   
  #=> [10, {:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]},
  #    {:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 12]}] 
k #=> 10 
o #=> {:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11]} 
n #=> {:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 12]}
```

We wish the block to return:

```
{:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11, 12]}
```

which we can do most easily like so:

```
{ :option_id=>o[:option_id],
  :option_style_ids=>o[:option_style_ids] | n[:option_style_ids] } 
  #=> { :option_id=>10,
  #     :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11] | [9, 12]
  #=> { :option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11, 12]}
```

`h[10]` is set to this value, so now:

```
h #=> {10=>{:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11, 12]},
  #     7=>{:option_id=>7, :option_style_ids=>[19]}}
```

which, because we are finished enumerating `enum`, is the value returned by `each_with_object`. The final step is to extract the values of this hash:

```
h.values
  #=> [{:option_id=>10, :option_style_ids=>[9, 10, 11, 12]},
  #    {:option_id=> 7, :option_style_ids=>[19]}]
```

Comment: Although I marked another answer as correct, I really appreciate you taking the time to explain this! Do you know, in terms of performance, how your method compares to using `inject`?

Comment: I don't know how this compares with `inject` performance-wise. If I had to guess I'd put my money on `inject`, but it would be easy to benchmark the two.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly the output you want, but you could convert it from here.

```
require 'set'
src = [...your original array of hashes...]
style_ids_by_option_id = {}
src.each do |e|
  style_ids_by_option_id[e[:option_id]] ||= Set.new
  style_ids_by_option_id[e[:option_id]].merge(e[:option_style_ids])
end
```

This would result in a data structure like this:

```
{10=>#<Set: {9, 10, 11}>,
 7=>#<Set: {19}>,
 8=>#<Set: {1}>,
 5=>#<Set: {4, 5, 2}>,
 12=>#<Set: {20}>}
```

Comment: If you used an array, rather than a set, it would be `src.each_with_object({}) do |h,sids|; id = h[:option_id]; sids[id] ||= []; sids[id] |= h[:option_style_ids];
end #=> {10=>[9, 10, 11], 7=>[19], 8=>[1], 5=>[4, 5, 2], 12=>[20]}`.